# How can we create or list the Tags to Azure Virtual Machine in .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I want to list and change the tags and their values for the Azure Virtual Machines using .NET SDK.

Please let me know the way for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done so far and what problems you're facing.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Thanks for replying. I have just started on looking at the dll  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources and the classes for it which are mentioned in MSDN. But I am not finding any useful documentation which can guide me to authenticate and set up the request for listing and creating tags for particular VM or Resource Group. Your help will be most appreciated.

Comment: @GauravMantri Could you please help me in this.

Comment: Will it work if I share the code to update tags for a resource group? Unfortunately I don't have a Virtual Machine ready at the moment where I can try the code out. Please let me know.

Comment: Yeah Sure. have you used the Rest API or using the .NET SDK?

Comment: I am creating ResourceManagementClient using credentials but it doesnot allow me to create object of the client.            TokenCloudCredentials credential = TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionid, token);
            try
            {
                var client = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials);
              }

Comment: @GauravMantri : Please let me know how you are able to do that

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have a Virtual Machine handy, I am posting code for updating tags for a Resource Group.

First, please ensure that Azure AD application is properly set up. You may find this link useful for that purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx.

Next, I created a simple console application. What you would need to do is get [`Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager 1.0.0-preview`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/1.0.0-preview) and [`Active Directory Authentication Library 2.22.302111727`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.22.302111727) Nuget packages in your application.

After that, things are pretty simple. Please see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources;
using Microsoft.Rest;

namespace AzureARMDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ClientId = "<your-application-client-id>";//This is the PowerShell Client Id
        private static string TenantId = "<tenant-id>";
        private static string LoginEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        private static string ServiceManagementApiEndpoint = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        private static string RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
        private static string SubscriptionId = "<your-azure-subscription-id>";
        private static string AzureResourceManagerEndpoint = "https://management.windows.net";
        private static string ResourceGroupNameToUpdate = "<resource-group-name-to-update>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GetAuthorizationHeader();
            var credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
            var resourceManagerClient = new ResourceManagementClient(new Uri(AzureResourceManagerEndpoint), credentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId,
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Listing resource groups. Please wait....");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            var resourceGroup = resourceManagerClient.ResourceGroups.List().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == ResourceGroupNameToUpdate);
            if (resourceGroup != null)
            {
                var tags = resourceGroup.Tags;
                if (!tags.ContainsKey("Key1"))
                {
                    tags.Add("Key1", "Value1");
                }
                else
                {
                    tags["Key1"] = tags["Key1"] + " Updated";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Updating resource group. Please wait....");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                resourceManagerClient.ResourceGroups.Patch(ResourceGroupNameToUpdate, resourceGroup);
                Console.WriteLine("Resource group updated.");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
            }
            //var resourceGroups = resourceManagerClient.ResourceGroups.List();
            //foreach (resourceGroup in resourceGroups)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Resource Group Name: " + resourceGroup.Name);
            //    Console.WriteLine("Resource Group Id: " + resourceGroup.Id);
            //    Console.WriteLine("Resource Group Location: " + resourceGroup.Location);
            //    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            //}
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the application");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetAuthorizationHeader()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            var context = new AuthenticationContext(LoginEndpoint + TenantId);

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                result = context.AcquireToken(
                  ServiceManagementApiEndpoint,
                  ClientId,
                  new Uri(RedirectUri));
            });

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Name = "AquireTokenThread";
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            string token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Thanks for your answer and it was very useful. However, it would update the tag to entire resource group but how we can achieve to update the tag to particular virtual machine.

Comment: Is there any way where we can update the tags to specific virtual machine only

Comment: Of course you can update tags for a specific virtual machine only. I chose resource groups as an example to demonstrate how you can update tags using resource manager library as I didn't have a virtual machine. I would suggest you use the library to understand it better and then use it for your scenario.